# Best way to install cfn-bootstrap utilities on CentOS 8

Tags: amazon-cloudformation, centos8

I'm working on a CentOS 8 based instance/launch configuration in AWS and would like to use cfn-init to manage some of the setup/provisioning steps.

However, I'm finding that the provided RPM does not deploy, since the way Python2 and Python3 have been packaged up differs enough that the AWS supplied RPM can't find its dependencies.

The command I'm using to install is: `yum install -y https://s3.amazonaws.com/cloudformation-examples/aws-cfn-bootstrap-latest.amzn1.noarch.rpm`

This is resulting in the following error:

```
Error: 
 Problem: conflicting requests
  - nothing provides python >= 2.6 needed by aws-cfn-bootstrap-1.4-34.noarch
  - nothing provides python-setuptools needed by aws-cfn-bootstrap-1.4-34.noarch
  - nothing provides python-daemon needed by aws-cfn-bootstrap-1.4-34.noarch
  - nothing provides pystache needed by aws-cfn-bootstrap-1.4-34.noarch
```

Which I suspect is because python in CentOS <= 7 is now python2 in CentOS8.

What would be the best way to install these tools in this instance?

Comment: What is the problem you are having?

Comment: I've added a comment with the error I get when using the rpm. I'm currently trying to see if I can just use the .tar.gz, although installation is much more fiddly going that route so I'm hoping there's a cleaner solution.

Comment: Wow, that seems to have been packaged for Amazon Linux 1, which is even older. And it looks like you are [not supposed to use the RPM anyway](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cfn-helper-scripts-reference.html), _except_ on Amazon Linux. Remember that **Amazon Linux is not compatible with CentOS** despite their repeated irresponsible false claims that it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, in the end I went with unpacking the tarball and performing the installation via the UserData script. This was done by adapting [existing guides](https://computingforgeeks.com/how-to-install-aws-cloudformation-helper-scripts-on-centos/) for how to do it via the CLI

This results in quite a long script, and the version below installs only Python2 due to some issues getting the AWS tools to run on Python3 (for my use case I only need Python for this, otherwise I'd figure out how to work around that).

```
      "UserData" :  {"Fn::Base64" : {
        "Fn::Join" : ["", [
          "#!/bin/bash\n",
          "mkswap /dev/nvme1n1\n",
          "swapon /dev/nvme1n1\n",
          "yum -y update\n",
          "yum -y install https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-8.noarch.rpm\n",
          "yum -y install python2 python2-pip\n",
          "pip2 install pystache\n",
          "ln -s /usr/bin/python2 /usr/bin/python\n",
          "curl -O https://s3.amazonaws.com/cloudformation-examples/aws-cfn-bootstrap-latest.tar.gz\n",
          "tar xvf aws-cfn-bootstrap-latest.tar.gz\n",
          "cd aws-cfn-bootstrap-*/\n",
          "python setup.py build\n",
          "python setup.py install\n",
          "mkdir -p /opt/aws/bin\n",
          "ln -s /usr/init/redhat/cfn-hup /etc/init.d/cfn-hup\n",
          "chmod 775 /usr/init/redhat/cfn-hup\n",
          "ln -s /usr/bin/cfn-hup /opt/aws/bin/cfn-hup\n",
          "ln -s /usr/bin/cfn-signal /opt/aws/bin/cfn-signal\n",
          "ln -s /usr/bin/cfn-init /opt/aws/bin/cfn-init\n",
          "ln -s /usr/bin/cfn-get-metadata /opt/aws/bin/cfn-get-metadata\n",
          "ln -s /usr/bin/cfn-signal /opt/aws/bin/cfn-signal\n",
          "ln -s /usr/bin/cfn-send-cmd-event /opt/aws/bin/cfn-send-cmd-event\n",
          "ln -s /usr/bin/cfn-send-cmd-result /opt/aws/bin/cfn-send-cmd-result\n",
          "/opt/aws/bin/cfn-init -v",
            " --stack ", { "Ref" : "AWS::StackName" },
            " --resource VPNServerLaunchTemplate",
            " --region ", { "Ref" : "AWS::Region" }, 
            "\n"
        ]]
      }}
    }
```

**EDIT** - So apparently there is a Python3 compatible version that can be downloaded from https://s3.amazonaws.com/cloudformation-examples/aws-cfn-bootstrap-py3-latest.tar.gz. For more details check the [AWS Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cfn-helper-scripts-reference.html).